# What does the casting director mean by "be authentically, anatomically not Jewish" in Friends?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In the *Friends* episode [The One With Ross and Monica’s Cousin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583556/combined), Joey auditions with a casting director; the plot is as described:

> The Casting Director: Terrific! Well uh, there’s one more thing. Uhh, uh it’s really important to the director that everything in this
> movie is authentic. Yeah and so in your love scene with Sarah she
> talks about how she’s never seen a naked man who wasn’t Jewish. So…
> (Laughs.)
>
> Joey: So…What?
>
> The Casting Director: So uh well the director is insisting that
> whoever play that part be authentically, anatomically not Jewish. Do
> you know what I’m saying?
>
> Joey: Yes!
>
> The Casting Director: Okay.
>
> Joey: No. What?
>
> The Casting Director: An Italian Catholic immigrant at this time would
> not be…
>
> Joey: Bar Mitzvahed?
>
> (The casting director shakes her head.)
>
> (Joey thinks about it and finally realizes what she means.)

Then later at Monica's apartment

> [Scene: Monica and Chandler's, Joey is telling Monica what the casting
> director was trying to get too.]
>
> Monica: So to get this part you can’t be?
>
> Joey: Nope.
>
> Monica: But you are?
>
> Joey: Yep.
>
> Monica: But you told them you weren’t?
>
> Joey: That’s right.
>
> Monica: Wow! Wow! And it’s definitely all gone? There’s nothing there
> to work with? (Joey glares at her.) What were you thinking?

Am I missing something here?  What exactly does the casting director mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They mean his foreskin. Joey has been [circumcised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcision), which means his foreskin was removed when he was young. Thus, he and Monica try to fashion a fake foreskin so he can portray an uncircumcised man, a plan that ultimately fails.

Though Joey is a Catholic Italian, circumcision is a common global procedure and [it is estimated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalence_of_circumcision) that 30% of the males in the world and around 55% of the males in the U.S. are circumcised.